# How to prepend lines with variables through find, exec and sed?

Tags: bash, sed, find, latex

I can't succeed to combine the different advices and answers to partly similar questions answered before on the forum so I'll ask my own question, hoping someone may share ideas to resolve this :-)

So here is the project :

- I've got a lot of .tex files
- I'm restructuring them to a better management (systematized) system using a kind of metadata
- They're all supposed to have tagged lines that I'd like to reshape.

### The input files look like this :

```
\section{the title}
\status{Work in progress}

content
```

Titles are obviously all different and status vary from "To do" to "Work in progress" and "Writen".

### The needed output :

```
\renewcommand{\TITLE}{the title}
\renewcommand{\STATUS}{\Doing}

\section{\TIT}

\STA

content
```

### Sythesis

- Title needs to stay the same (which is why I suppose I'll need a variable)
- Status need to be standardized
- Part of the prepended text is systematized

Any idea ? :-)

Comment: Have you tried with sed?

Comment: Yes, as I have a bunch of directories and files I started with `find -name '*tex' -exec sed '/status|section/p' {} +` to get the occurrences but I don't know what to do afterward to insert them back on the first line

Comment: Learn to modify *one* file before you attempt to modify *all* of them.

Comment: To expand on that, you have four independent problems. 1) modify the `section` line, 2) modify the `status` line with the addition of a couple of lines, 3) save the modifications to the file, 4) operate on all of the tex files at once.  You should attempt all four *separately,* then ask us for help with the one(s) that you have trouble with.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice, I'll keep in touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Beta, you should probably break your problem into several sub-problems which you can solve independently. Let's start by finding a way to transform sections, then statuses, then combine both, and last but not least, combine all of that to run on several files.

### Transform title (one file)

We can use `sed` to detect sections and transform them into two lines: renewcommand and new section.

```
sed -r 's/\\section\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\TITLE}{\1}\n\\section{\\TIT}/g'
```

It works like so:

```
echo '\section{The title}' | sed -r 's/\\section\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\TITLE}{\1}\n\\section{\\TIT}/g'
```

Will result into:

```
\renewcommand{\TITLE}{The title}
\section{\TIT}
```

### Transform status (one file)

We can apply a very similar transformation for the status:

```
sed -r 's/\\status\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\STATUS}{\1}\n\\STA/g'
```

Which will transform:

```
\status{Work in progress}
```

into:

```
\renewcommand{\STATUS}{Work in progress}
\STA
```

### Combine both (one file)

Now you can easily apply one sed after the other on a given file:

```
sed -ir \
  -e 's/\\status\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\STATUS}{\1}\n\\STA/g' \
  -e 's/\\section\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\TITLE}{\1}\n\\section{\\TIT}/g' filename.tex
```

This will apply both transformations to `filename.tex` and change it in-place.

### Apply to several files

Now you can apply this `sed` command on all files in your folder (recursively) using `find` and `xargs` to invoke the command on each file:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sed -ri  \
  -e 's/\\status\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\STATUS}{\1}\n\\STA/g' \
  -e 's/\\section\{([^}]+)\}/\\renewcommand{\\TITLE}{\1}\n\\section{\\TIT}/g' {}
```

The `find . -name '*.tex' -print0` will list all `tex` files recursively. Then `| xargs -0 -I{} command {}` will invoke `command` on each individual file.

I would make sure that you *back-up* (or version-control) all your files before attempting such transformations. Just to make sure you can roll-back in case something goes wrong.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It requiered a few step by step `find -exec sed` to prepare every doc so they are straightly structured, and worked perfectly ! Thks !